# custom navigation drawer that loads its items via http does not render

Tags: flutter

I have a newly generated Flutter app with the sidebar aka a navigation drawer on the side. Instead of having static, predefined list items I'd like to query a http service to fill the list items with data I receive from the service.

The main.dart is pretty much the generated file, without the Drawer. Instead I created a sidedrawer.dart that holds a StatefulWidget and its state. There is also the http service.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobilesite_flutter/sidedrawer.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: SideDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

sidedrawer.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobilesite_flutter/tag.dart';
import 'dart:developer';


class SideDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _SideDrawerState();
}

class _SideDrawerState extends State<SideDrawer> {
  var tags = new List<Tag>();

  _getTags() {
    log('loading tags');
    TagService.findAll().then((value) => this.tags = value);
    log('tags loaded');
    for (var tag in this.tags) {
      log(tag.toString());
    }
  }

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getTags();
  }


  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
        child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemCount: this.tags.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            log(this.tags.toString()); // <-- never called
            return ListTile(title: Text(this.tags[index].name));
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And the service:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Tag {
  final String name;
  final String slug;

  Tag({this.name, this.slug});

  factory Tag.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Tag(
      name: json['name'],
      slug: json['slug'],
    );
  }

}

class TagService {
  static Future<List<Tag>> findAll() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://somedomain.com/api/v1/tags/');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Iterable list = json.decode(response.body);
      return list.map((model) => Tag.fromJson(model)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load tags');
    }
  }
}
```

I pretty much glued this together from what I could find on the web.

What's wrong? When I press the hamburger the drawer is white.
In sidedrawer.dart I've marked the part that is never executed.
Sadly I can't use log() inside the promise success callback as it complains that I should upgrade to a later version (of something I don't remember).

I have CORS set, that's not the issue, I have an angular app that fetches data from it and that one works flawlessly. When I log what's returned from the web service endpoint (with toString()) I receive many "instance of Tag", so there is data. But the build method of `_SideDrawerState` never seems to be called.

What do I have to do so the items that are loaded from the web service are rendered?

p.s.
The final "product" shall be an initial virtual scrolling list of cards, on the side there should be a list of tags content is associated with, when I click on a tag it should filter content by tag slug, when I click on a card it should open a new view which should show content details. Very similar to a blog. But for now I'd be happy with just holding the tags in its own stateful widget, which should provide navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Of course... after I posted the question I found the answer myself.

I have of course to update the state of the widget with `setState(callbackFn())`

```
  _getTags() {
    TagService.findAll().then((value) => setState(()=> {tags = value}));
  }
```

however I had to update the `pubspec.yaml` file because the Android Studio IDE had showed a warning.

> "Set literals weren't supported until version 2.2, but this code is
>   required to be able to run on earlier versions. Try updating the SDK
>   constraints."

It still runs with

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

but the warning is here.